# Document's Certified Copy UK

Tags: united-kingdom, certification

I moved to the UK from continental Europe around one year ago. Recently, I applied for a credit card. I thought I was declined, however today I received mail from the bank asking me to provide more details — namely, confirm my identity and address. I have to provide a "certified copy" of my ID card. They provide a list of "who can certify" which includes "post office, your bank, lawyer, solicitor, *serving Police officer*, Doctor (GP) etc."
This is completely new for me. How does this work? Is it a completely normal thing to ask a police officer (which one?) to certify a photocopy of my ID? Or go to a GP and ask them?

Is this a common thing to do?

I am a bit afraid that I will look like an idiot, as I certainly would if I went to a doctor in my home country and asked them to do such a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gov.uk has a nice overview](https://www.gov.uk/certifying-a-document). In practice, you go to that person, show them both the original and the copy, they write sign it

If you know, e.g, a teacher, they might simply do it for you free-of-charge. Otherwise, you can go to the post office ([details here](http://www.postoffice.co.uk/document-certification-service)) and get it done for a fee (probably the simplest solution if you are not too sure about the process).

Finally, if your bank has a physical presence, they should be able to do it themselves too. The point being that you have to show your ID at the counter instead of merely sending a non-certified copy.

Comment: Thank for the answer! However, I understand the process, but have doubts whether is something common to do in the UK or I will look like an idiot asking people to do so...

Comment: @M4ks It's common, don't worry, I wouldn't grab a random police officer on patrol but why would you look like an idiot just asking? Check the post office website, you will see it's so common that they built a service around it. You can even use the website to locate a branch offering it to be absolutely sure you won't show up at the wrong place. That should put any concern to rest.

Comment: It's fine to get a random police officer to certify something, but if you try to get them to attend an emergency as a pretense, then you will be in *trouble*